# Blank screen displays After running Angular 4 web app project First time

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I try to run my first Angular 4 js web project. so I have installed node.js for my npm manager and I am using visual studio code as an editor. After following the below steps. I get the blank screen as a result. kindly help me to solve this Issue.

**Steps I followed:**

- npm install -g @angular/cli
- ng new PROJECT
- cd PROJECT
- ng serve

After performing the above steps server is up. but when Navigate to  http://localhost:4200/ . it shows blankpage.

**app.components.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
</div>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyFirstApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

[image]

**Browser Console**
[image: Browser Console]

[image: Chrome Console shows Error]

Comment: What is inside your app.module.ts? Is any error displayed in console?

Comment: I happens with bigger application, You could put your `own loader`/`splash screen` in between `app-root` tag..

Comment: Any console error display in Development mode ?

Comment: Check the console and terminal for errors thrown. You could've also installed the cli twice by accident

Comment: @Maciej Treder ,@Kasunjith Bimal I have added my console and app.module.ts as screen shot.

Comment: HI @austinthedeveloper Howto find I have installed cli twice . kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What about the errors reported in Chrome console? There are any?

Comment: Run through the "Updating Angular CLI" steps for the global CLI. It will uninstall and re-install it: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: No errors is shown in my IE browser console.@ Maciej Treder

Comment: Hi @austinthedeveloper . I tried this                                                 Global package:
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest but still got issues.

Comment: @shimaan you try any other Browser and check browser console in chrome

Comment: @KasunjithBimal . I tried with chrome browser it shows error. I have posted the screen shot for your reference.

Comment: check in your console error in double click the error and disable your browser extension.and try after

Comment: @shimaan <script src="ft-polyfill-service.herokuapp.com/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script> add this file your index.html file.i think solve your Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined error

Answer (score 0):

1 . `npm i mdn-polyfills --save`

2. and modify the file under the project src\polyfills.ts, add following code

// or load it before other angular2 & zone.js stuff

```
import "core-js/client/shim"; 

import "zone.js";

import "reflect-metadata";
```

3.`ng build` and then hit enter.

4.`ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your production build using the build in dev server you can run.

**> ng serve --prod**

Answer (score 0):

I ran through similar problem. I was actually trying to run the Angular app in sub-folder while angular created path for custom JS files and pointed to the root folder.

This got solved 2 ways:
1. I copied only JS files from compiled app to root folder and it started working.
2. Tried to run whole app in root folder and never faced same issue.

Your problem might be different than what I faced, but shared my experience if it could help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. But my problem get resolved by performing following steps in command prompt:

1. ng build and then hit enter.
2. ng serve

I hope it will help you as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @varinderjit  .After solving that issue. I got an issue in Windows 10 machine some times working some times not . so I prefer to go Linux . Now angular is working like charm.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Shimaan. I will also try the same.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.
Open angular.json in the root folder.
change this line "index": "src/index.html", to "index": "src/app/app.component.html",